# Need to make insert data in another table with customize pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table name "table1" like these columns :

```
id  code  price

1   1000  5.3
2   1001  4.3
3   1002  6.5
4   1003  7.5
```

What I need to insert these data in to table "table2" to be like this :

```
id  code  price   code1   price2

1   1000  5.3     1001    4.3
2   1002  6.5     1003    7.5
```

The question : is that possible ? and if so , how can I do it ?

- Note : I searched a lot of in sites and not found as I want .

Comment: What are the rules for the rows and columns?

Comment: The rules : will be in even and odd as you said .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the even and odd codes in separate columns by using:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(code)) as id,
       max(case when code % 2 = 1 then code end) as id_1,
       max(case when code % 2 = 1 then price end) as price_1,
       max(case when code % 2 = 0 then code end) as id_2,
       max(case when code % 2 = 0 then price end) as price_2
from t
group by ceiling(code / 2.0)
```